# Properties of Variance for Random Variables

Tags: random-variables, variance

Need help this question

Random Variables $X$ and $Y$ are independent. If $Var(X) = 4$ and $Var(Y) = 9$.
Find $Var(2X-3Y-1)$

So this is what I did but it seems to be incorrect.

$Var(2X-3Y-1)$

$=Var(2X)-Var(3Y-1)$

$=2^2Var(X)-3^2Var(Y)$

$=4(4)-9(9)$

$=16-81$

$=-65$

Answer (score 1):

Variances always add, so the answer should be $16+81=97$.

Comment: So then the minus in between the 2X and 3Y attaches to the 3 as a negative right?

Comment: @Viserom No. It just disappears into a +, no matter what sign it was originally.

Comment: @Viserom Or else you could say that $-3$ is squared, yes.